# When Trying to Add the Digits of A number in Java, 5+0 = 53?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basic function to add the digits of a number together, so putting in `54` would output `9`. Currently putting in `54` puts out `105`. My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(sumOfDigits(54));
}

public static int sumOfDigits(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    char digit;
    for(int x = 0;x < (Integer.toString(num).length()); x++) {
        digit = Integer.toString(num).charAt(x);
        //This Prints 'Sum: 0 Digit: 5'
        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum + " Digit: " + digit);
        sum += digit;
        //This Prints 'Sum: 53 Digit: 5'
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + " Digit: " + digit);
    }
    return(sum);
}
```

The println before the addition prints `Sum: 0 Digit: 5` and then prints `Sum: 53 Digit: 5;` (the first time through the loop), so it seems to me it is adding 0 and 5 together and getting 53.
I have no Idea what is going on here, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'5' != 5`. `'0' != 0`.

Comment: Something Like this? int temp = Character.getNumericValue(digit);

Comment: sum += Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(digit));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is using Unicode, it means the value of a char is Unicode value. You should convert it to the number value before adding them.
So try the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(sumOfDigits(54));
}

public static int sumOfDigits(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    char digit;
    for(int x = 0;x < (Integer.toString(num).length()); x++) {
        digit = Integer.toString(num).charAt(x);
        //This Prints 'Sum: 0 Digit: 5'
        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum + " Digit: " + digit);
        sum += (digit - '0');
        //This Prints 'Sum: 53 Digit: 5'
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + " Digit: " + digit);
    }
    return(sum);
}
```

Comment: That Worked, thanks for your trouble, I'm pretty new to this

Comment: Well, char *is* a number, but in terms of arabic-numerals, they are severely offset, eg, the digit '4' is decimal '52' in ascii. Theoretically you could just subtract 48 off each number and that's the conversion from char to int done

Comment: @MaximSrour Yes, you are right, I will edit it. Thanks

Comment: True true, but it's still technically correct :P I need to get used to calling it Unicode instead of Ascii, been making that mistake for a while now

Answer (score 2):

You are currently summing the ascii value of the digits. Instead, use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-) to correctly perform this conversion (***or*** subtract the literal `'0'`). You can also use `String.valueOf(int)` and `String.toCharArray()` and a `for-each` loop. Like,

```
public static int sumOfDigits(int num) {
    int sum = 0;
    char[] digits = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
    for (char ch : digits) {
        sum += Character.digit(ch, 10); // or ch - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

public static int sumOfDigits(int num){
     int sum = 0;
     while(num > 0){
         sum = sum+ (num%10);
         num = num/10;
  }
```

What you are doing is adding the character ASCII value